# Orbeon - saxon parse() stop working in new version

Tags: saxon, orbeon

I have problem with function saxon:parse() in my form. I used it in Orbeon 2020.1.2 CE and it worked well. After update to version 2021.1.2 PE (I have prebuild) it stop working. I try same thing on orbeon.com too with same bad result (https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/b57d32a03929e4be3b6cc391497dc14fb48bd878)

Strange is when i try same thing saxon:parse(//xml) in xforms-inspector it work well (I change $ from form to // in inspector). Is some change in using saxon in new version or I hit some bug? Thank you

Comment: Do you get any specific error message?

Comment: Please note that this isn't really a Saxon question, because unless things have changed recently, Orbeon uses a forked version of a rather old Saxon release.

Comment: `saxon:parse()` should still work but indeed it causes an error in your example, and I see where this has regressed for 2021.1. Note that we have now `xf:parse()`, which is a newer XForms function. You can use this as a workaround, or, indeed, a better solution.

Comment: FYI I entered issue #5271 to track this. https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/5271

Comment: Yes, xf:parse() work for me well. Thank you!

Comment: I posted a summary of @ebruchez 's comments in the answer below; nothing really new there, but those finding this through a search will save themselves the need of reading this comments thread. -Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Orbeon Forms 2021.1, you can't use `saxon:parse()` anymore, and should use `xf:parse()`, which is a new XForms 2.0 function (see [differences between XForms 1.1 and 2.0](https://www.w3.org/community/xformsusers/wiki/XForms_2.0#Differences_between_XForms_2.0_and_XForms_1.1_.28Non-Normative.29)).

In new code, it is always better to use `xf:parse()`. However, for backward compatibility, it would be good for Orbeon Forms to also support `saxon:parse()`, and this is tracked as issue [#5271](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/5271).